# jQuery advanced select detecting and click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have multiple li's that contain a form.

In the form I have a select with a few options in a drop down menu.

I want to create a jquery script so that if you click submit AND the select has been changed from the default (selected) option, then hide the li. The li's have unique id's.

**Example code :**

```
<li id="<?php echo 'li_'.$unique ?>">
    <form id="<?php echo 'form_'.$unique ?>">
        <select id="<?php echo 'select_'.$unique ?>">
            <option value='apple' selected>Default</option>
            <option value='pear'>Different</option
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="<?php echo 'submit_'.$unique ?>"/>
    </form>
</li>
```

**What I want to achieve here..**

```
// Script ->  On .click submit and if selector != selected .hide this <li>

$("<?php echo '#submit_'.$unique ?>").click(function(){
     $("<?php echo '#select_'.$unique ?>").change(function() {
         if ($(this).val() != 'apple') {
            $("<?php echo '#li_'.$unique ?>").hide();
        };
     });
});
```

**I also tried..**

```
$("<?php echo '#submit_'.$unique ?>").click(function(){
     if ($("<?php echo '#select_'.$unique ?>").val() != 'apple') {
        $("<?php echo '#li_'.$unique ?>").hide();
     };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/122/)**.

You don't have to use the php code to generate the js code you could create a global event for all the li's :

```
$("[id^='submit_'").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var unique = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
  var default_value = $('#select_'+unique+' option:first').val();
  var current_value = $('#select_'+unique).val();

  if(current_value!=default_value)
      $('#id_'+unique).hide();
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("[id^='submit_'").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var unique = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
  var default_value = $('#select_'+unique+' option:first').val();
  var current_value = $('#select_'+unique).val();

  if(current_value!=default_value)
    $('#id_'+unique).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="id_1">
    <form id="form_1">
      <select id="select_1">
        <option value='apple' selected>Default1</option>
        <option value='pear'>Different1</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" id="submit_1"/>
    </form>
  </li>
  <li id="id_2">
    <form id="form_2">
      <select id="select_2">
        <option value='apple' selected>Default2</option>
        <option value='pear'>Different2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" id="submit_2"/>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```